# GitLab installation fail on Debian

Tags: debian, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm trying to install GitLab on a Debian 8.5.0. I folow the [installation guide](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#debian8) but the last step fail and I don't find any information in documentation.

The gitlab-ctl reconfigure finish by

```
Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 3 resources updated in 02 seconds
```

I have this error in the logs :

```
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8]'
```

The generated gitlab.rb is enterely commented except the external_url.

gitlab-ctl status say

```
run: redis: (pid 12852) 2309s, got TERM; run: log: (pid 12429) 3636s
```

The web interface can't be reach.

gitlab-ctl stop fail in timeout.

Here the full return of gitlab-ctl reconfigure

```
Starting Chef Client, version 12.12.15
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["gitlab"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - runit (0.14.2)
  - package (0.0.0)
  - gitlab (0.0.1)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Recipe: gitlab::default
  * directory[/etc/gitlab] action create (up to date)
/sbin/init : option non reconnue « --version »
-.mount                                                                                   loaded active mounted   /
  Converging 288 resources
  * directory[/etc/gitlab] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * directory[Create /var/opt/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/embedded/etc] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/gitconfig] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::web-server
  * group[gitlab-www] action create (up to date)
  * user[gitlab-www] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::users
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * group[git] action create (up to date)
  * user[git] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/.gitconfig] action create (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-shell
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/git-data] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/config.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab_shell_secret] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/.gitlab_shell_secret] action create (up to date)
  * execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions] action run
    - execute /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions
  * bash[Set proper security context on ssh files for selinux] action run (skipped due to only_if)
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/lfs-objects] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/builds] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/working] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/tmp] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/upgrade-status] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/backups] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/gitlab-rails-rc] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.secret] action delete (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/secret] action delete (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/database.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/database.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/secrets.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/secrets.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/resque.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/resque.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/aws.yml] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/aws.yml] action delete (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/smtp_settings.rb] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb] action delete (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/relative_url.rb] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/relative_url.rb] action delete (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/gitlab.yml] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/rack_attack.rb] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/rack_attack.rb] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/.gitlab_shell_secret] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/HOME] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/RAILS_ENV] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/SIDEKIQ_MEMORY_KILLER_MAX_RSS] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/BUNDLE_GEMFILE] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/PATH] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/ICU_DATA] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab-rails/env/PYTHONPATH] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/tmp] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/uploads] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/log] action create (up to date)
  * link[/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sidekiq.log] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/schema.rb] action create (up to date)
  * remote_file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/VERSION] action create (up to date)
  * remote_file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/REVISION] action create (up to date)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/RUBY_VERSION] action create (up to date)
  * execute[chown -R root:root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public] action run
    - execute chown -R root:root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
  * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * bash[generate assets] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/config.ru] action delete (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-ci-proxying
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-ci-http.conf] action delete (up to date)
Recipe: gitlab::add_trusted_certs
  * directory[/etc/gitlab/trusted-certs] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs] action create (up to date)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs/README] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[Move existing certs and link to /opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs] action run (skipped due to only_if)
Recipe: gitlab::default
  * service[create a temporary unicorn service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * service[create a temporary ci-unicorn service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * service[create a temporary sidekiq service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * service[create a temporary ci-sidekiq service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * service[create a temporary mailroom service] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: runit::systemd
  * directory[/usr/lib/systemd/system] action create (up to date)
  * cookbook_file[/usr/lib/systemd/system/gitlab-runsvdir.service] action create (up to date)
  * file[/etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/gitlab-runsvdir.service] action delete (up to date)
  * execute[systemctl daemon-reload] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * execute[systemctl enable gitlab-runsvdir] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * execute[systemctl start gitlab-runsvdir] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: gitlab::redis
  * group[gitlab-redis] action create (up to date)
  * user[gitlab-redis] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/redis] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/redis] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.conf] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/log] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/log/main] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/log/run] action create (up to date)
  * template[/var/log/gitlab/redis/config] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[reload redis svlogd configuration] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * file[/opt/gitlab/sv/redis/down] action delete (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/init/redis] action create (up to date)
  * link[/opt/gitlab/service/redis] action create (up to date)
  * ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep] action run (skipped due to not_if)
  * service[redis] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * execute[/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl start redis] action run
    [execute] ok: run: redis: (pid 12852) 1511s, got TERM
    - execute /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-ctl start redis
Recipe: gitlab::postgresql
  * group[gitlab-psql] action create (up to date)
  * user[gitlab-psql] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data] action create (up to date)
  * directory[/var/log/gitlab/postgresql] action create (up to date)
  * link[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data] action create (skipped due to not_if)
  * file[/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.profile] action create (up to date)
  * directory[create /etc/sysctl.d for kernel.shmmax] action create (up to date)
  * file[create /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf kernel.shmmax] action create (up to date)
  * link[/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmmax.conf] action create (up to date)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-postgresql.conf kernel.shmmax] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-unicorn.conf kernel.shmmax] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab.conf kernel.shmmax] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab.conf kernel.shmmax] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * execute[load sysctl conf kernel.shmmax] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * directory[create /etc/sysctl.d for kernel.shmall] action create (up to date)
  * file[create /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf kernel.shmall] action create (up to date)
  * link[/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.shmall.conf] action create (up to date)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-postgresql.conf kernel.shmall] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-unicorn.conf kernel.shmall] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab.conf kernel.shmall] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab.conf kernel.shmall] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * execute[load sysctl conf kernel.shmall] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * directory[create /etc/sysctl.d for kernel.sem] action create (up to date)
  * file[create /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf kernel.sem] action create (up to date)
  * link[/etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab-kernel.sem.conf] action create (up to date)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-postgresql.conf kernel.sem] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-unicorn.conf kernel.sem] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc/90-omnibus-gitlab.conf kernel.sem] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * file[delete /etc/sysctl.d/90-omnibus-gitlab.conf kernel.sem] action delete (skipped due to only_if)
  * execute[load sysctl conf kernel.sem] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8] action run
    [execute] The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "gitlab-psql".
              This user must also own the server process.

              The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C.UTF-8".
              The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

              fixing permissions on existing directory /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data ... ok
              initdb: could not create directory "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/pg_xlog": No space left on device
              initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data"

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
    ---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 ----
    STDOUT: The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "gitlab-psql".
    This user must also own the server process.

    The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C.UTF-8".
    The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

    fixing permissions on existing directory /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data ... ok
    STDERR: initdb: could not create directory "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/pg_xlog": No space left on device
    initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data"
    ---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 ----
    Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 returned 1

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/postgresql.rb

     84: execute "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D #{postgresql_data_dir} -E UTF8" do
     85:   user postgresql_user
     86:   not_if { File.exists?(File.join(postgresql_data_dir, "PG_VERSION")) }
     87: end
     88: 

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/postgresql.rb:84:in `from_file'

    execute("/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8") do
      action [:run]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :execute
      command "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8"
      backup 5
      returns 0
      user "gitlab-psql"
      declared_type :execute
      cookbook_name "gitlab"
      recipe_name "postgresql"
      not_if { #code block }
    end

    Platform:
    ---------
    x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 3 resources updated in 02 seconds
```

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm a idiot.

```
STDERR: initdb: could not create directory "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data/pg_xlog": No space left on device
```

My disk is just full.
I extended my volume and it work.