# Gitlab Omninbus Core: Indexer setup fails with "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"

Tags: gitlab-omnibus

When setting up an Omnibus Gitlab 12.7.5 Enterprise Edition, on the step where ElasticSearch is integrated, the indexer setup fails with "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory" when issuing the command:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:indexer:install[/home/git/gitlab-elasticsearch-indexer] RAILS_ENV=production
```

At first, it complained of git not owning some subdirectories of /var/opt/gitlab. That warning disappeared when I `chowned` them to git

Then it started complaining about "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"

Being a complete Ruby iliterate, here are the steps taken to solve it:

- Search in forums, googling it, hope stackoverflow groups would have relevant info...
- Setup bundler by apt: `sudo apt  install ruby-bundler`, it appears installed but the error persists:

```
XXX@gitlab:~$ sudo dpkg -l ruby-bundler
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-====================================================================
ii  ruby-bundler                    1.16.1-1             all                  Manage Ruby application dependencies (runtime)
```

- Set up bundler through the recommended setup: `sudo gem install bundler`, appears to setup OK, but the error persists

```
Fetching: bundler-2.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.1.4
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.1.4
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

- Tried cd-ing to /var/opt/gitlab as suggested on some SO cases but the error is still there

/var/opt/gitlab/.bundle is empty, I do not know it that is a clue of some mis-setup

Any help welcome with the issue, it is surely caused by my lack of Ruby command

[EDIT:]
Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39515492/2979393) I have found that my disk is almost full (28.3 GiB used out of 30). I will increase it while waiting for some real knowledge on the issue => no luck there, clearly it is not a space issue

[EDIT2:]
Given that the home dir specified for user git in passwd is /var/opt/gitlab I have tried executing the command using that dir as installation dir, that is: `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:indexer:install[/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-elasticsearch-indexer] RAILS_ENV=production` but the "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory" error is still there

[EDIT3:]
Seems that in the [product features page](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/self-managed/feature-comparison/) the ElasticSearch integration is a "Bronze"(paid) feature. That might be the cause why the indexer refuses to install on my "Core" (free) system. I had set a post on Gitlab Forums to confirm, hope to get some useful info soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

Gitlab takes out of the UI the fields to properly configure this unless you pay a license -you can run an Enterprise Version without paying a license-

I understand the business logic behind it but nevertheless it should be more documented

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I'm working with premium version and I stumbled also to the exactly same problem. After that I realized that our gitlab enterprise edition 12.7.5 was actually already installed with the indexer. I don't know if that can be the case with your version.

I got indexing running with:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:elastic:create_empty_index && gitlab-rake gitlab:elastic:index
```

Comment: Hi, Tuppikake, thanks for the help.

That's part of the following section, "Adding GitLab’s data to the Elasticsearch index"

I have tried the command `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:elastic:create_empty_index` but it failed with 'Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9200 (localhost:9200)'

I guess that is because I cannot set the ElasticSearch host and port because it does not appear on "Settings"->"Integrations", due to being CORE.
I will wait for confirmation on the official forums and mark your answer as correct if so